# Copying and pasting using Python for files with similar but not exact names

Tags: python-3.x

I have two folders each with several files.

Folder 1:

1. abc_1600_efg.xlsx
2. abc_1601_efg.xlsx
3. abc_1602_efg.xlsx
4. abc_1603_efg.xlsx

Folder 2:

1. ijk_1600_xyz.xlsx
2. ijk_1601_xyz.xlsx
3. ijk_1602_xyz.xlsx
4. ijk_1603_xyz.xlsx
5. lmn_1600_tuv.xlsx
6. lmn_1601_tuv.xlsx
7. lmn_1602_tuv.xlsx
8. lmn_1603_tuv.xlsx

Assuming the files in each folder are randomized, anyone have any ideas on how to use python 3.x to copy from file 'abc_1600_efg.xlsx' in folder 1 then have python search for the corresponding file in folder 2 ('ijk_1600_xyz.xlsx'). The number portion of the title is the key that needs to be matched. Then I want to paste the data into the file 'ijk_1600_xyz.xlsx' (folder two has two files with the same number 1600 but I need to find just the 'ijk_1600_xyz' file).

I want to loop this so that this would be done for every file in folder 1 starting at 1600 then 1601 then 1602 etc. I have the copy and paste portion finished I'm just stuck on the search and match portion.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it 
but something like:

```
import re,os
for file1 in os.listdir(folder1):
       match=re.match('..._(\d+)_.*'),file1).group(1)
       for file2 in os.listdir(folder2):
           if ('_'+match+'_' in file2) :
                ... copy ...
```

Anyway, you should know how to adapt to these situations.

Comment: This will not work. Remember there is no file in folder2 that ends with `efg` for example

Comment: Yes, fixed. Anyway, this is not profound, and the question isn't as well.